# How to generate this sequence programmatically

Tags: arrays, math

How can i generate dynamically this array.

```
var posX:Array = [0,-20,20,-40,0,40,-60,-20,20,60,-80,-40,0,40,80,-100,-60,-20,20,60,100]
```

The numbers in the array refer to the x position of the object. I use it to place objects in triangular formation.

```
     0
   -20 20
  -40 0 40
-60 -20 20 60 etc
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d:Number = 20;
var a:Array = [];
for(var i:Number = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for(var j:Number = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        a.push(d * (2 * j - i));
    }
}
trace(a.join());
```

The first number of each row is the negative of the zero-based-row-index times `d` : which is `- i * d`
Each subsequent number in a row exceeds the previous one by `2*d`. Hence subsequent numbers = first-element + 2 * d * zero-based-index-within-the-row

Which is = `- i * d + 2 * d * j`  = `d * (2 * j - i)`

Comment: I started with `start = -i * d;` and so on...  Cleaned up the code and added a little explanation.

Comment: Can anyone rename the title of the question in order for others to find this solution easier. My am not fluent in english...

Answer (score 0):

This code outputs subsequent elements of your array for ten row of your triangular formation:

```
var x:int;
var y:int;
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < y + 1; x++) {
        trace(20 * ( -y + 2 * x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know actionscript but pseudocode is like this:

```
for (row=0; ; row++)
{
   maxVal=20*row;
   for (val=-maxVal;val<=maxVal;val+=40)
    posX.append(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code for each row in f# :

```
let StepN n = 
    let n = -(n*20)
    [
    for x in [n..40..-n] do
        yield x
    ]
```